# How to access/use variable or data from one function expression to another function expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a function expressions like

```
$scope.myCourse = function(param1, param2) {
  $scope.courseName = param2;
  $scope.courseType = param1
}
```

I need to access the variable/data from  `$scope.myCourse` in another function expression like

```
$scope.updateCourse = function() {
  // here how to access/use $scope.courseName and  $scope.courseType from $scope.myCourse
}
```

am getting undefined when doing like this

```
$scope.updateCourse = function() {
      console.log($scope.courseName, 'and', $scope.courseType, 'are in current selection. Are you fine to change the COURSE and TYPE?')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to declare $scope.courseName and  $scope.courseType outside the function, so that it can be accessible from any other function.